# Is $o(x^n)$ unique?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

If I have that $f(x)=T_n(x)+o(x^n)$ ($T_n$ is the Taylor polynomial of $n-$th order ) and $f(x)=p(x)+o(x^n)$, is this $o(x^n)$ the same "thing" in both terms?

So why I'm asking this question. The reason is that I will like to show that $p=T_n$.

$f(x)-p=o(x^n)$

I know that $o(x^n)=q$ (where as $q$ is the zero polynomial) in the limit $x\to 0$.

Comment: The equation $f(x)=T_n(x)+o(x^n)$ is more properly written as $f(x)-T_n(x)\in o(x^n)$. Since $o(x^n)$ represents the class of all functions $g$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to0}|g(x)|/x^n=0$. In that sense $o(x^n)$ is not a unique function, but a set of functions.

Comment: However, your original problem is not the problem "Is $o(x^n)$ unique?" Your original problem is "Is $T_n$ unique?". Well, among all functions it is not. However, among all polynomials of degree at most $n$ it is. You can see this by subtracting both equations. You get that $p(x)-T_n(x)\in o(x^n)$. Since $\frac{p(x)-T_n(x)}{x^n}$ must tend to zero as $x\to0$. Then all coefficients of $p$ and $T_n$ must coincide.

Comment: @flan Thanks for your comments! I find them very insightful.

Comment: @flan What do you mean by subtracting both equations?. Also, how do I show $p=T_n$ in the right notation?

Comment: You have that $f(x)-T_n(x)\in o(x^n)$ and that $f(x)-p(x)\in o(x^n)$. Then $p(x)-T_n(x)=(f(x)-T_n(x))-(f(x)-p(x))\in o(x^n)$. Now, since $\frac{p(x)-T_n(x)}{x^n}\to0$ when $x\to0$ and $p(x)-T_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree not larger than $n$, we must have $p(x)-T_n(x)=0$.

Comment: To see the last claim write $p(x)-T_n(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$. Then $\frac{p(x)-T_n(x)}{x^n}=\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}}+...+\frac{a_n}{1}$. If $a_0\neq0$, then the fraction would tend to $\infty$. Likewise for $a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}$. Finally, if all of these are zero and $a_n\neq0$, then the limit would be $a_n$. Since the limit is $0$, then $a_n=0$ too.

Comment: @flan thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $g(x)= o(x^n) $, we must precise where, so we have to write
$$g(x)=o(x^n) \Bigl( x\to a, x\in A\Bigr)$$

with
$$A\subset D_g \text{ and } a\in \overline{A}$$

this will mean that
$$g(x)=x^n\epsilon(x)$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to a,x\in A}\epsilon(x)=0$$
For example, if $n\ge 1$,

$$e^{-x}=o(x^n) (x\to +\infty)$$
$$\ln(x)=o(x^n) (x\to +\infty)$$

Comment: Very short, understandable and insightful !

Comment: But In my case it is the same thing. Because in both cases $x\to 0$. Do you agree?

Comment: @Xenusi Yes, the decomposition is unique.$p=T$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah If $p$ is also a polynomial of degree not larger than $n$. If $p$ is allowed to not be a polynomial, or to have degree larger than $n$, then it is not unique.

Comment: @flan $p$ is a polynomial with $\deg(p) \le n$. Thanks for pointing it out. I also think that Haman assumed this.

Comment: @Xenusi I also assumed it, but I needed to make it explicit, since you didn't mention it, they didn't either, and the result doesn't hold without it.